# Grep from nginx server files, but exclude www.domain.tld

Tags: server, bash, nginx, grep, awk

I have a command in a bash script like this, to get me an array of all the domains on my webserver.

```
domains=($(grep -rnw '/etc/nginx/sites-available/' -e 'server_name' -l | xargs grep -e 'server_name' | awk '{print $3}'))
```

The format of an nginx server file has the server name row, prefixed with a tab, and then `server_name domain.tld;`

This works fine and I get a list of just the domain names back, but only if the www. prefix is not defined in the server name row. In that case, the server name row would look like `server_name www.domain.tld domain.tld;` or `server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;`, both ways acceptable.

**Q:** In the case the www. prefix is defined, I get back whatever is first in the order. Is there a way I could ignore the `www.domain.tld` part from the results, to only get back `domain.tld`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed` you can try this:

```
domains=$(grep -rwn "/etc/nginx/sites-available/" -e "server_name" | sed -E -e 's/ www\.\w+\.\w+//g')

printf "%s\n" "$domains"
```